# Dygraph "relative" Axis y2 and y for one graph

Tags: javascript, apache-axis, dygraphs

I have a graph with values ​​from 0-40000 (y2-axis) As an example: In a time window the values ​​are 33000-37000. This can be seen on the right side axis-Y2. Now I want to have an axis Y on the left that shows relative values: that is, from 0-4000 in this example ... and at the same time to the right axis Y2 ... do you understand my concern?

[image: Example]

Thanks Jerry

Comment: Added image from link

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the question correctly you are trying to put two different y axes on a single graph.

Dygraphs has built in support for this.

When creating a new graph:

```
  g = new Dygraph(
      document.getElementById("graphDiv"),
      data,
      {
        labels: [ 'Date', 'Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3', 'Y4' ],
        series: {
          'Y3': {
            axis: 'y2'
          },
          'Y4': {
            axis: 'y2'
          },
        },
        axes: {
          y: {
            axisLabelWidth: 60
          },
          y2: {
            // set axis-related properties here
            labelsKMB: true
          }
        },
        ylabel: 'Primary y-axis',
        y2label: 'Secondary y-axis',
      }
  );
```

This is taken directly from the dygraphs 2 axes demo page which can be found here:
http://dygraphs.com/tests/two-axes.html

Comment: Thanks in advance ... but my problem is, how does the second axis get the relative values? Look at my picture...painting

Comment: You want y2 to be dynamically populated based on the y1 values? This is more of a data problem than a charting problem in my opinion. I think the cleanest way is adding the y2 data to the json before handing it to dygraphs